# Notify host of event from app within emulator

Tags: android

Is there a way for my app (which is running in an emulator) to notify the host/pc of some app-specific event (e.g. when my app crashes)?

One idea I had was to use adb logcat and have my app write the message to the logs.  My host/pc would then read the logs (using adb logcat) and wait for the message to come.  This approach seems a bit hacky though and from my understanding, logcat can be buffered so it's possible that the log message will show up much later.

Comment: Are You Looking for Crash Report APIs.....??

Comment: No sorry. I guess the crash was a bad example.  I was hoping for some mechanism for the app to notify the host.  For example, "If" there was something like "adb wait-for-some-event" where adb would just hang until the app within the emulator triggered the event.